# Rails 3, Rspec testing an XML API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, post, rspec, rspec2

I have an API that expects/accepts in the body XML and can return json or XML. I'm trying to test this with rspec.

To make the request I do the following in my spec:

```
post "/resources?auth_token=#{@user.authentication_token}", post_data, {
    "CONTENT_TYPE" => 'application/xml',
    "ACCEPT" => 'application/json'
}
```

It works as expected until it gets to responding.It seems to be ignoring my ACCEPT header and returning an html document with a space as the body. I've tested the API using a restclient with the same headers and it works fine.

Is there something I'm missing here? On a side note... I can't figure out how to print the request headers in the controller which could be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed!

I needed to use HTTP_ACCEPT for the accept header

i.e

```
post "/resources?auth_token=#{@user.authentication_token}", post_data, {
    "CONTENT_TYPE" => 'application/xml',
    "HTTP_ACCEPT" => 'application/json'
}
```

Argh so annoying...